# ASP.NET C# MVC How to get a property of controller from the View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to get a property of controller from the View "_Layout.cshtml"?

I have the property "DisplayName" (string) and i need get this property in view.

Comment: can you provide more information, as what you are trying to achieve and what you currently have

Comment: I defined the title in controller and need show de the title in view.

For example:
ControllerCar, have the property "Title".

I need show this title in "_Layout.cshtml"

Comment: This value should be passed in the ViewModel like any other value.

Comment: Voting to reopen as this question seem to be relatively popular (even if it does not show research effort). May benefit from either alternative answer or good duplicate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't access properties of a controller from view or layout because the controller that started particular view is gone by the time view is rendered.

Instead of trying to get access to controller you should pass information via model or [ViewBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.108).aspx):

In controller:

```
ViewBag.DisplayName = this.DisplayName;
```

In views:

```
@ViewBag.DisplayName
```

Note that there could be multiple controllers involved into rendering of the page.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: @BrianPickens original request made was confusing as there really no "the controller" as I've noted in the post.  My post shows standard solution that should be used when one tries to "access property of controller from view/layout"... And workarounds are considered valid answers - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335964/are-workarounds-considered-relevant-answers... But I agree that this did not offer exact answer - updating.